# Generating Shibboleth SP Metadata

Tags: metadata, single-sign-on, shibboleth

I'm trying to configure Shibboleth SSO on an application that runs locally (on localhost).
I've followed all the instructions and configured my shibboleth2.xml file, but I'm having troubles when the following link accessed `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata` or `http://127.0.0.1/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata`

I've also tried `http://127.0.0.1/MyAppName/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata` , but didn't work either!

Am I missing something? Can anyone help me solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please try also contact the Shibboleth "users" mailing list http://shibboleth.net/mailman/listinfo/users

Comment: What Web server are your running ?

Answer (score 6):

Did u tried the below URL ?

`https://localhost/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata` (remember it is case sensitive)

If you are using a IIS 7,  IIS 6 Management Compatibility should be installed on IIS 7.x since the Shibboleth installer package uses those management interfaces. The IIS 6 Management Compatibility option can be installed from Administrative Tools > Server Manager > Web Server (IIS) > Role Services.

For a detailed setup instructions, you can look into this [post](https://wiki.cac.washington.edu/display/infra/Install+Shibboleth+Service+Provider+2.5+on+Windows+and+IIS).

Comment: It was advised that not to substitute your server's full domain name in place of "localhost"

Answer (score 1):

Similar symptom here due to the request being proxied to the actual service (gitlab). Solution:

```
<Location /Shibboleth.sso>
  ProxyPass !
  SetHandler shib
</Location>
```

See [Shibboleth documentation](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPApacheConfig#NativeSPApacheConfig-MakingURLsUsedbymod_shibGetProperlyRouted) for details.